# Python os.py behaves like a package. Why?

Tags: python, import, module, package

The following operation works

```
from os.path import normcase
```

As far as I'm concerned it shouldn't. "os.py" is not a directory so not a package. os does contain path which is itself another module.

Furthermore

```
>>> import os
>>> os.__package__
''
>>>
$ grep __package__ /usr/lib/python3.10/os.py
```

So module "os.py" has a **package** attribute but it doesn't declare this attribute in its file.

What dark magic is this?

The reason I care is because I'm going very deep into import mechanisms. Developing a context manager to take care of sys.path while importing.

Comment: Simple trick: `import posixpath as path`. (There's `ntpath` too.)

Comment: That's what os.py does. But why does import path from os work whern os.py is not a packagew. Or is it a package because it declares __package__. But where does it declare __package__

Comment: It's not a package, it's a module. And every module has an attribute `__package__` with an empty string as default.